# Passing value from javascript prompt to managed bean

Tags: cdi, prompt

Is it possible to pass a value from a popup prompt to a CDI managed bean somehow like this:

```
h:commandButton image="/resources/images/editButton.png" onclick='mytext = prompt("Enter text: ")' action='#{myBean.foo(mytext)}'
```

The prompt opens, the foo method is called, but how do I pass the mytext value?

Comment: I don't know how you'd do that with JS, but it seems like http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/confirmDialog.jsf will do what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a hidden input, change your JS to set the value of that input on the hidden field and send that to the server.